# Looking for different approach to find $\left(x_1+\frac1{x_1}\right)\left(x_2+\frac1{x_2}\right)\left(x_3+\frac1{x_3}\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math, roots

> If $x_1,x_2,x_3$ be roots of $x^3+3x+5=0$, find the value of
> $$\left(x_1+\frac1{x_1}\right)\left(x_2+\frac1{x_2}\right)\left(x_3+\frac1{x_3}\right)$$

To solve this problem I expanded the expression and used [Vieta's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) and got the answer $-\frac{29}5$
. but I wonder is there any other approach to solve this problem?

I tried this way as an alternative ansewr:

Consider $x_1,x_2,x_3$ be roots polynomial $P(x)=x^3+3x+5$. then $\frac1{x_1},\frac1{x_2},\frac1{x_3}$ are roots of $P(\frac1x):$

$$P(\frac1x)=0\quad \rightarrow \quad P(\frac1x)=(\frac1x)^3+\frac3x+5=0\rightarrow 5x^3+3x^2+1=0$$
But I don't know whether it helps or not.

Comment: You could also cook up the cubic equation satisfied by $y_i=x_i+x_i^{-1}$ by explicitly computing $y_i,y_i^2, y_i^3$ as a quadratic in $x_i$ (remembering $P(x_i)=0$ so $x_i^{-1}=-\frac15(x_i^2+3)$ etc.).  That are 3 quadratics in $x_i$ so you can eliminate $x_i^2$ and $x_i$, giving (after simplification) $5y^3+3y^2+29=0$ so the product of roots is -29/5.

Comment: By the way using the second polynomial that you wrote does help a bit if you expand the right way.

Comment: @user10354138 Can you please write it as answer? this approach seems interesting because it is the continuation from the point I left. but I couldn't understand this method it yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

we have to find $$\frac{(x_1^2+1)(x_2^2+1)(x_3^2+1)}{x_1x_2x_3}$$ now $$P(x)=x^3+3x+5=(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)$$ Notice that $$P(i)P(-i)=(x_1^2+1)(x_2^2+1)(x_3^2+1)$$ now use $x_1x_2x_3=-5$ to finish..

$i=\sqrt{-1}$  and $P(i)P(-i)$ can be easily found and is left as an exercise

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I found $P(i)P(-i)=29$ and the final answer $\frac{-29}{5}$ ;) but my question is how you recognized $P(i)P(-i)=(x_1^2+1)(x_2^2+1)(x_3^2+1)$? was it intuitively ?(I can only get it with calculating)

Comment: @Soheil $(x-i)(x+i)=x^2+1$ is a well known identity

Comment: Yes. but here we used $(i-x_k)(i+x_k)$

Comment: I don't get it I got : $$P(i)P(-i)=(i-x_1)(i-x_2)(i-x_3)\times (-1)^3(i+x_1)(i+x_2)(i+x_3)$$

Comment: @Soheil multiply  each $-1$ to each $i-x_k$

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: Let the roots of $$x^3+3x+5=0 ~~~~(1)$$  be $a,b,c$, then $a+b+c=0, ab+bc+ca=3, abc=-5$.
Let $$F=(a+1/a)(b+1/b)(c+1/c)=\frac{(a^2+1)(b^2+1)(c^2+1)}{abc}=\frac{y_1 y_2y_3}{abc}=\frac{y_1 y_2 y_3}{-5}$$
where $y_1=(a^2+1)$ etc. let us transform $x$ equation to $y$ equation as $y=x^2+1 \implies x= \sqrt{y-1}.$ Putting it in (1) and simplifying we get $$y^3+3y^2-29=0$$ Hence $y_1y_2y_3=29$ and finally, $$F=\frac{-29}{5}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I calculated this and got $y^3+\color\red{3}y^2-29=0$ also it doesn't affect on the final answer.

Comment: Oh! yes you are write, I have now corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

I'll expand on my comments above.

You want to find a cubic polynomial satisfied by $y=x+x^{-1}$ whenever $x$ is a root of $P$.  Note that $x^3+3x+5=0$ gives $5x^{-1}=-(x^2+3)$ and $5x^{-3}=-(3x^{-2}+1)$.  Therefore
\begin{align*}
-5x^{-1}&=x^2+3\\
25x^{-2}&=(x^2+3)^2=x^4+6x^2+9\\
&=x(-3x-5)+6x^2+9\\
&=3x^2-5x+9\\
-125x^{-3} & = 25(3x^{-2}+1)\\
&=9x^2-15x+52.
\end{align*}
Thus
\begin{align*}
5y &=5x+5x^{-1}=-x^2+5x-3\\
25 (y^2-2) &=25 x^2 +25 x^{-2} =28x^2-5x+9\\
125 (y^3-3y) &=125 x^3 + 125 x^{-3} =-9x^2-360x-677
\end{align*}
Eliminating $x^2$ gives
\begin{align*}
25 (y^2-2)+140y &=135x-75\\
125 (y^3-3y)-45y &=-405x-650
\end{align*}
or equivalently,
\begin{align*}
5y^2+28y &=27x-5\\
25y^3-84y &=-81x-130
\end{align*}
Now eliminate $x$ and we have
\begin{align*}
-145=-81x-130+3(27x-5)&=(25y^3-84y)+3(5y^2+28y)\\
&=25y^3+15y^2
\end{align*}
i.e.
$$
5y^3+3y^2+29=0
$$
so the product of roots $y$ is $-29/5$.

*Remark*: This is essentially the "standard method" for finding a polynomial equation for $y_i=q(x_i)$ where $q$ is a polynomial and $x_i$ are the roots of some polynomial $P$.